# IE with position absolute element will create horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to use `position: absolute` to create a centered element, but it will create a horizontal scrollbar on Internet Explorer 11. Please see the script below. Anyone here knows how to fix this problem?

***Update:** I figured out that using `overflow:hidden` seems to solve this problem somehow. But when there are another one outside of the `container`, it will be hidden as well.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /*This one is not the solution, though*/
}
.content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.another-content {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="another-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add following properties with the position absolute in `IE`

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
right: 0;   
left: 0;
bottom:0;   //specify all including bottom:0
```

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar show up in all browsers, not only IE. You can do the following:

- The biggest issue is that the `left: 50%` and `width: 80%` together are adding to the total width and forcing the horizontal scrollbar to show up in some browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer and MS Edge). You set the width to 80%, so divide the remaining 20% between the left and right border and you'll end up with 10% each. Simply use `left: 10%` to achieve the same result, but without the side effect of the horizontal scrollbar.
- Also when you set the size to 100% and then add border, those borders will be out of the view and cause the scrollbars to show up. This is the same in all browsers. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to force the browser to include the border in the height and width calculation.
- The `height: 100vh` makes the box height equals to the view port. However, the `body` has default margins which vary from one browser to another. You can either set those margins to zero `body { margin: 0; }`, or change the height to `height: 100%` which is 100% of the container which the `body` in this case.

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Though they are not direct solution, they helped me a lot to figure out how to solve it.

The cause is as what Racil Hilan said. When I use `left:50%` and `width:80%`, the content width will be added up and create a horizontal scroll, which is not ignored by only IE. And my point is to avoid creating that added-up width. Here is my two way to workaround this one.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.another-content {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="another-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```